# Perl Script With Oracle Variables

Tags: oracle, perl

We have tons of perl scripts that run from many servers. It gave an error when I ran from a different server as below:

```
/db/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/dbhome_1
```

In the perl script, I noticed a line "Use DBI". I am not familiar with the perl. So just wondering how do I change the settings for perl to take the latest 11.2.0.4 and not 11.2.0.3.

There are thousands of scripts so it is not convenient to pass the export command manually in them.
I am hoping to figure where the variable is set for oracle_home when the perl script is executed.

Comment: Have you had a chance to see this [page](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Perl)?

Comment: That OraFAQ page is ancient.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing. Perl and DBD::Oracle don't provide any default for that variable. Whatever is setting it is part of the environment that's been provided on your servers, which SO can't possibly tell you anything about.